# Audio spectrum analyzer for Windos Store App

Tags: windows, audio, windows-store-apps, analyzer, spectrum

I want to add a spectrum analyzer to my Windows Store Application. Are there any libraries that allow to do this? I write my application using C#/XAML.

P.S. It must not necessarily be a spectrum analyzer. It can be something that allows me to visualize audio stream. For example, this library can get audio stream frequency or amplitude in every moment.

Comment: where is your picture?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete "see picture below".

Comment: How would you like to visualize the audio? Oscilloscope (amplitude vs. time)? Frequency spectrum? Power meter? All 3? Some are easier than others.

Comment: As I wrote in P.S., it can be everything that allows me to visualize audio stream. I need it for my radio player. Ultimately I need element that can produce visual effects corresponding to playing audio. For example it can be a needle whose motion depending on audio amplitude.